# What is the best way to insert multiple form arrays into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have written a PHP script that automatically generates and populates an HTML form.

The HTML output is something like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="product-1">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_price[]" value="0.99">

    <input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="product-2">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_price[]" value="1.39">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

My MySQL Database format is: `product_name, product_price`

What method should I use in `process.php` to insert this information into a MySQL database?

If it were just the one array (for example, `product_name`) then I'd write the following code:

```
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];

foreach ($product_name as $n){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (product_name)
    VALUES ('$n')";
    $conn->query($sql)
}
```

But of course this foreach approach does not work with multiple arrays. I thought about and tried populating `product_name` first, and then creating foreach loop to UPDATE the `product_price` row, but this isn't working for me and feels very messy. I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this.

What would be the correct way to handle this?

Comment: One at a time is usually best

Comment: I'd suggest fixing your table so that you're not using two different arrays, and use a key for each `product[1]['name']` and `product[1]['price']`, or `product['product_1']['name']`, etc.

Comment: I dont get it, both fields are hidden.

Comment: @aynber How would I then handle the post data? As in, how can I route it to the correct column?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The user sees something different. The hidden input is purely for passing data to the processor script.

Comment: Well if you showed us all the relevant code we could provide a fuller answer

Comment: @aynber totally unnecesary and over complicated

Comment: @RiggsFolly That is all the relevant code. It doesn't matter that the field is hidden, the question only relates to handling the POST data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not really, when you're trying to keep similar items together.

Comment: @Syn You'd iterate through `$_POST['products']` where each value would be an array containing the name and price, which you can then insert into the columns you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use one of the post arrays to control the loop and then you use the index gained from the foreach i.e. `$i` to access any/all the other arrays

PDO

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price) VALUES (:name,:price)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach ($_POST['product_name'] as $i => $n){
    $stmt->execute( array(':name'=> $n,
                          ':price'=>$_POST['product_price'][$i]) 
                        )
                );
}
```

MYSQLI

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, qty) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach ($_POST['product_name'] as $i => $n){
    $stmt->bind_param("sdi", 
                        $n, 
                        $_POST['product_price'][$i]
                        $_POST['product_qty'][$i]
                    );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the MYSQLI approach. How would you go about managing additional fields? Say for example I had more than just product_price, for example, product_quantity?

Comment: In that same way as with product_price assuming they were also in equivalent arrays

Comment: Could I trouble you for an example please? I have not used bind_param before, nor have I prepared queries, so just trying to get my head around the code.

Comment: See amended MYSQLI methid

Comment: Thank you. I understand how this works. I appreciate your time

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you build your form exactly in parallel, so that an arbitrary index `product_name[x]` will also always be associated with the same index `product_price[x]`, then simply use foreach's extended key=>val syntax and use that key to access the "parallel" values in the other arrays:

```
foreach($_POST['product_name'] as $key => $name) {
   $price = $_POST['product_price'][$key];
   ... do db stuff with $name/$price...
}
```